# Find max in excel based on a group

Tags: excel-2010

I have an Excel spreadsheet that has multiple rows I need to interrogate as a group.  How would I find the max row for this grouping?

Here's a sample of my data.

```
CLMID   Seq
1408400 00
1408400 01
1408400 02
```

I can have 1 or more rows with the same CLMID and then the Seq field identifies each iteration of that grouping. I tried  `=MAX(IF(OR(F2=F3,F2=F1),1,0)*G:G)` but that gives me 0 on row 1, 1 on row 2 and 2 on row 3.  I would like to just flag the max row in the group and leave the rest blank.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: =MAX(IF(OR(F2=F3,F2=F1),1,0)*G:G)  where CLMID is in column F and Seq is in column G.

Comment: put a picture to ilustrate the problem

Comment: Where is the function entered?

Comment: do yow want to have a column with 1 for the max Seq for each CLMID??

Comment: Yes, I want to flag the max sequence for each CLMID so that I can use that flag in other calculations.

Comment: I am not able to post a picture as some of the data is sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare your CLMID column from current row to row above:

H3: `=IF(F2=F3,0,1)`
H4: `=IF(F3=F4,0,1)`

And so on...

Comment: I don't understand how that would give me the max for the grouping?

Comment: That's because you don't explain yourself and you ignore the comments people leave. If that's not what you wanted, correct your question so that it's understandable

Comment: I responded to the questions asked in as timely a fashion as I could.  I was not ignoring anyone's comments.  If you don't understand my question, you could ask for clarification instead of leaving nasty comments.  I did say in my original question that I would like to just flag the max row in the group and leave the rest blank.

Comment: I didn't leave a nasty comment. As far as I *still* understand, my answer does what you wanted. Did you try it?